# pass .validating on textbox through to user control

Tags: vb.net, events, user-controls

I have a user control with a text box, panel, and monthly calendar control on it. I would like to have the .validating event raised only for the text box, but I would like to use it as

```
Sub userControlName_Validating(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) handles userControlName.Validating
```

Is there a way I can have the user controls validating event be the text box's validating event?

Comment: That is not the correct signature, e should be `As CancelEventArgs` but `Handles TextBoxControlName.Validating` should work

Comment: Right, but I have a UserControl with many controls on it. I want to be able to use my control in the same fashion as other winforms controls without having to subscribe to custom event handlers on my main form.

Comment: It works the same for controls on the UC as on a form.  Each has its own validating events